# Identifying generic type of class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there any way to detect the type specified in a generic parameter on a class?

For example, I have the three classes below:

```
public class Customer
{ }

public class Repository<T>
{ }

public class CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>
{ }

public class Program
{
    public void Example()
    {
        var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Repository<>)).GetTypes();
        //types contains Repository, and CustomerRepository
        //for CustomerRepository, I want to extract the generic (in this case, Customer)
    }
}
```

For each of the repository objects brought back, I'd like to be able to tell what type is specified.
Is that possible?

EDIT

Thanks to @CuongLe, got this which is working, however looks messy....
(also help from resharper ;))

```
var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Repository<>))
 .GetTypes()
 .Where(x => x.BaseType != null && x.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault() != null)
 .Select(x => x.BaseType != null ? x.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault() : null)
 .ToList();
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided valid c#. And the 3rd class, while valid, did you mean something like `public class CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>` ?

Comment: *var repositories = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Repository<>))* this is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you now hold the type of `CustomerRepository` by selecting from list of types:

```
var customerType = typeof(CustomerRepository).BaseType
                          .GetGenericArguments().First();
```

**Edit:** You don't need to *trust* Re-Sharper 100%. Since you do `Where` to select all type whose `BaseType` is not `null`, needless to check again in `Select`. For more, `FirstOrDefault` actually return `null`, this code is optimized:

```
 Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Repository<>))
                  .GetTypes()
                  .Where(x => x.BaseType != null)
                  .Select(x => x.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault())
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).

Comment: Tried that, just comes back with Name = T .... not the "Customer" type I would expect?

Comment: please elaborate what type you are calling this on.

Comment: @alexjamesbrown - i mean what are you calling `GetGenericArguments` on?