# Casting generic to interface type - Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have some classes like this:

```
public class Customer
{ }

public interface IRepository 
{ }

public class Repository<T> : IRepository
{ }

public class CustomerRepository<Customer>
{ }
```

Then, as per [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462900/identifying-generic-type-of-class-using-reflection) I can use reflection to get a list of types referenced by generics for each of my *Repository:

What I want to end up with is a `Dictionary<Type, IRepository>`

So far, I have this:

```
Dictionary<Type, IRepository> myRepositories = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Repository<>))
.GetTypes()
.Where(typeof(IImporter).IsAssignableFrom)
.Where(x => x.BaseType != null && x.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault() != null)
.Select(
    x =>
    new { Key = x.BaseType != null ? x.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault() : null, Type = (IRepository)x })
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Type);
```

However, it doesn't like my cast `(IRepository)x`
I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'My.Namespace.IRepository'.

Comment: How are you *expecting* it to get an instance when you've only got a `Type`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot cast `(IRepository) type` with type is `Type` class,

you can use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create object `CustomerRepository`, you also don't need to use `Select`, instead, use `ToDictionary` directly, the code below:

```
var myRepositories = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Repository<>))
       .GetTypes()
       .Where(x => x.BaseType != null && 
                   x.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault() != null)

       .ToDictionary(x => x.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault(), 
                            x => Activator.CreateInstance(x) as IRepository );
```

Comment: This solution is not working when constructor of activating object needs some parameters.

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is a `System.Type` object, like if `x` is `typeof(Repository<>)`, you can't just cast it like that. The `Type` is not an instantiation.

If `x` had no "free" type parameters, that is if `x` where non-generic or *closed* generic, then `(IRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(x)` might create you an object of type `x`. But I'm not sure that's what you need. Will there be a parameterless instance constructor?